# CountIfS - Date clause

Tags: excel

Currently I'm counting absences for a person, and I'm tyring to add a date filter to it.  I have a working code to do this.

```
=COUNTIFS('Old Data'!$A:$A,Tracking!A7,'Old Data'!$B:$B,B5, 'Old Data'!D:D, ">1/1/2012")
```

The above code works and returns the values I want it to.  However, I need to be able to change the date, and year in multiple cells easily. So I created a drop down list in B4 in order to do this easily.

```
=COUNTIFS('Old Data'!$A:$A,Tracking!A6,'Old Data'!$B:$B,B5, 'Old Data'!D:D, >B4)
```

Is what I came to logically... but it doesn't work. If you take out the > sign then the cell is referenced, but once you put it in, the cell is no longer referenced. I've been searching for several hours now and can't seem to find anything that will make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when mixing cell references and operands in IF(S) formulas you must concatenate to build up the string

```
">"&B4
```

is what you want

Comment: You sir, rock. i had tried ">"B4 but didn't know about the & Excel Noobie here.   Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. and dont feel bad about not knowing something. Asking is the first step to knowledge (I have to ask tons of questions, not all on SO). Also I am a TA for a excel class at a top 20 Business school and most people in my classes take a while to get the hang of remembering to do this.

Comment: Just glimpsed at your profile... You TA at Kelly? I'm an Informatics student at IU. Go Hoosiers!  Not sure how to PM you, but I get back to Btown soon, I'll owe ya a beer sometime.

Comment: i'm glad to help. And yes, I TA for X201 in kelley and last semester I was a UI for CSCI-C311 with Prof Friedman (Intro to PL). you can use my email in profile if you want to.

Comment: Will do, I'll be in contact. Can't really email while at work, so it won't be until later.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS('Old Data'!$A:$A,Tracking!A6,'Old Data'!$B:$B,B5, 'Old Data'!D:D, ">" &B4)
```

Found this helpful article that should help you with your issue.
[countifs function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx)